# How to generate a v5 UUID with uuid_generate_sha1

Tags: c, hash, uuid, sha1

I want to generate a v5 UUID for a string using a given namespace.

https://man.archlinux.org/man/uuid_generate_time.3.en talks about `uuid_generate_sha1()` but I could not find any good examples on how to use them in our code.

My pseudocode looks like:

```
_generate_v5_uuid(const char *inputStr, const char *namespace, char **outputString)
{
        uuid_t uuid;
        uuid_generate_sha1(inputStr, &uuid);

        *outputStr = convert_uuid_to_string(uuid);
        return;
}
```

What exactly needs to be passed to `uuid_generate_sha1`?

Comment: At a glance of the docs, RFC, source, an output uuid, a UUID to be used as the namespace, a binary string (name) and its length. You could look at the [source for uuidgen.c](https://github.com/util-linux/util-linux/blob/master/misc-utils/uuidgen.c) for an example.

Comment: Thanks @Hasturkun I will check and update here

Comment: `What exactly needs to be passed to uuid_generate_sha1?` The signature is there `void uuid_generate_sha1(uuid_t out, const uuid_t ns, const char *name, size_t len);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written this example for you:

```
#include <uuid/uuid.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *convert_uuid_to_string(uuid_t uuid) {
    char *buf = NULL;
    size_t s = 0;
    FILE *f = open_memstream(&buf, &s);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
        fprintf(f, "%02x", uuid[i]);
    }
    fclose(f);
    return buf;
}


char *generate_v5_uuid(const char *inputStr, const char *namespace) {
    const uuid_t *ns = uuid_get_template(&namespace[1]);
    uuid_t uuid;
    uuid_generate_sha1(uuid, *ns, inputStr, strlen(inputStr));
    return convert_uuid_to_string(uuid);
}


int main() {
    system("set -x ; uuidgen --sha1 -n @url -N string");
    printf("%s\n", generate_v5_uuid("string", "@url"));
}
```

The program outputs:

```
$ ./a.out 
+ uuidgen --sha1 -n @url -N string
64be9091-88e8-5476-996b-8b541f7bf3e5
64be909188e85476996b8b541f7bf3e5
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Saved my life.
I was getting a crash with the above code inside uuid_generate_sha1().
Later realised from https://github.com/util-linux/util-linux/blob/master/misc-utils/uuidgen.c,  I am using a uuid as namespace, hence should use uuid_parse(namespace, ns); instead of uuid_get_template(&namespace[1]). I will paste my updated API below

Answer (score 1):

```
char *generate_v5_uuid(const char *inputStr, const char *namespace)
{
    uuid_t ns;
    uuid_parse(namespace, ns);
    uuid_t uuid;
    uuid_generate_sha1(uuid, ns, inputStr, strlen(inputStr));
    char str[UUID_STR_LEN];
    uuid_unparse(uuid, str);
    return strdup(str);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).